# JSSOR bullets doesn't follow slider when many pictures

Tags: jssor

I am trying to use this template of slider from JSSOR:
https://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.slider

In case a slider contains many pictures, for instance 100, some of the bullets are shown (the ones of pictures of the middle of the range, so 40 to 60 for instance) and they don't move, so it is not possible to select picture #90 for instance from the bullets. Also, bullets doesn't follow the slider and still display 40 to 60 at the beginning and at the end of the slider.

Is there a way bullets can "follow" the pictures at least and so show current numbers on screen ? In other words, how to make bullets sliding too ?

I tried to use several lines of bullets or decrease spaces. This shows more bullets but this is still not satisfying.

You can easily see the problem by downloading code, and in standard.html you can duplicate DIV sections related to pictures to have many of them and not only 8.